# .NET UWP XamlParseException error after update Visual Studio 2019 from 16.9.7 to 16.10.2

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, uwp, uwp-xaml

I've updated Visual Studio 2019 from 16.9.7 to 16.10.2 and my solution compiles but at runtime this exception is thrown:

```
Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException
  HResult=0x802B000A
  Message=Le texte associé à ce code d’erreur est introuvable.

Cannot deserialize XBF metadata type list as 'ToolbarButton' was not found in namespace 'Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.TextToolbarButtons'. [Line: 104 Position: 30]
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>
```

I have no "ToolbarButton" in my solution.
I have second machine with the 16.9.4 and it runs perfectly. Is it an issue of Visual Studio or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The error message could be related to `Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp`. Create a blank app and add the toolkit library to test might be useful.

Comment: I tried and there is no problem.

Comment: sounds like a VS issue. Submit a VS feedback from Visual Studio.